# What is gate symmetry?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, symmetry, gauge-invariance

I just read [this interesting interview with  Frank Wilczek](http://www.edge.org/conversation/frank_wilczek-power-over-nature) and he talks a couple of times about *gate symmetry*, without ever defining the term. This isn't a term I've come across, and google throws up a blank. What is gate symmetry, and are there any good references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that this interview was not transcribed by a physicist!

What he said was "Gauge Symmetry" not "Gate Symmetry".

Your googling should work better now, and here is one place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory